# Prevent SQL injection when using SQL Server database with mssql nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I try to use a database in SQL Server with nodejs mssql.
How can I prevent sql injection?

I tried using npm sqlstring

```
sqlstring.format(`use ?`, ['demo'])
```

But I get `'use 'demo''` and it gives me an SQL Server error.

When I tried `sqlstring.escape()` or `sqlstring.escapeId()`

```
use ${sqlstring.escape('demo')}`
```

I get the same error, any solution?

Comment: Why do you need to use a `USE`? Why not define the database you want to connect to in your connection string? Then there's no need to change the connection context within the SQL, as you're already connected to the correct database (`demo` in this case).

Comment: "it gives me an SQL Server error." - um, what is the error? You need to tell us in order for us to assist.

Comment: Don't use the `sqlstring` module, it's geared for use on MySQL servers. "Correctly" using the `??` placeholders for object identifiers with `SqlString.format('use ??', ['demo'])` outputs the string `use \`demo\`` which is great for MySQL but invalid on Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: On SQL Server you escape object names with `[]` not `\`\``. Equally, you should probably just connect to the correct database in the first place